# How to hide image-url if no attachment?

Tags: functions, images, post-thumbnails, attachments

How can I hide the img-tag if there is no attacment?

(function is from this tutorial: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/automagic-post-thumbnails-image-management/)

```
<img src="<?php get_attachment_picture();?>" />
```

I need something like this:

```
<?php if ( get_attachment_picture()) { ?>
<img src="<?php get_attachment_picture();?>">
<?php } else { ?>
show nothing, not even av default image
<?php } ?>
```

Here is the function I use:

```
<!?php 

/* Function to process your thumbnail & image
   Copy and paste the code below to your functions.php */

function get_attachment_picture(){
    global $post, $posts;
    $related_thumbnail =  get_post_meta($post->ID, 'image', $single = true);                            //read post meta for image url

    if($related_thumbnail == ""):
        $attachments = get_children( array(
                                    'post_parent'    => get_the_ID(),
                                    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
                                    'numberposts'    => 1,
                                    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
                                    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                                    'order'          => 'ASC',
                                    'orderby'        => 'menu_order ASC'
                                    ) );
        if(!empty($attachments)):                                               //check if there an attachment or not
            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
              if(wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id) != ""):
                  $related_thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );
              endif;
            }
        else:                                                           // if no attachment
            $first_img = '';
            ob_start();
            ob_end_clean();
            $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
            $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

            if(!empty($first_img)):
                $related_thumbnail = $first_img;
            else:
                $related_thumbnail = "images/default_thumbnail.jpg";                            //define default thumbnail, you can use full url here.
            endif;
        endif;
    endif;  

    echo $related_thumbnail;
} ?>
```

Comment: Could you provide more information? That's not a standard WordPress function, and without context we cannot help. A google search suggests you're trying to follow this: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/automagic-post-thumbnails-image-management/

Comment: **Again, please post the source code for get_attachment_picture** without it this question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're following this tutorial:

http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/automagic-post-thumbnails-image-management/

Replace the echo statement at the end of get_attachment_picture with a return, then change your image code.

Here is your new image code:

```
// get the URL of the image
$src = get_attachment_picture();

// if the url is not empty, display the image
if(!empty($src)){
    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $src; ?>" />
    <?php
} else {
    // the url was empty, do not display the image
}
```

Here's the modified function:

```
function get_attachment_picture(){  
    global $post, $posts;  
    $related_thumbnail =  get_post_meta($post->ID, 'image', true);                          //read post meta for image url  

    if($related_thumbnail == ""):
        $attachments = get_children( array(  
                                    'post_parent'    => get_the_ID(),  
                                    'post_type'      => 'attachment',  
                                    'numberposts'    => 1,  
                                    'post_status'    => 'inherit',  
                                    'post_mime_type' => 'image',  
                                    'order'          => 'ASC',  
                                    'orderby'        => 'menu_order ASC'  
                                    ) );  
        if(!empty($attachments)):                                               //check if there an attachment or not  
            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {  
              if(wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id) != ""):  
                  $related_thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );  
              endif;  
            }  
        else:                                                           // if no attachment  
            $first_img = '';  

            $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);  
            $first_img = $matches [1] [0];  

            if(!empty($first_img)):  
                $related_thumbnail = $first_img;  
            else:  
                $related_thumbnail = "";
            endif; 
        endif; 
    endif;   

    return $related_thumbnail; 
}
```

Comment: hi Tom, that didnt work. 1. you got an error in one line doubling '!emptyempty', but changed that and still didnt work

Comment: I'm looking for something like this <?php if ( get_attachment_picture()) { ?><img src="<?php get_attachment_picture();?>"><?php } else { ?>show nothing, not even av default image<?php } ?>

Comment: `$post--->ID` won't work ;)

Comment: tried without that to, still wont work. The function is fine and works well, but I need an if/else conditional code that can show the image if there is an attachement and then dont show anything if not. The code I have now shows a default image if no attachement image

Comment: Demilio that wouldn't make much sense, because either you would have the URL displayed twice, or you would have it not displayed at all, how does get_attachment_picture know if you want to return the value, or echo it out?

Comment: Demilio, look at the snippet of code **above** the function.

Comment: I've also edited the function again, I'm shocked net tuts would allow such sloppy code, I assumed it would work. I've also removed the default image from the function

Comment: I can see you have removed the url to the default image, but that would not do much with the <img> i use in the output section in my theme. I´m trying to hide the whole <img> tag in the output if there is no image attached. I think you are misunderstanding mu question (sorry for my bad explanations..)

Comment: I think you're ignoring that I have 2, not 1 snippet of code, with the default image removed, if there is no image specified, the function will return an empty string. The `if(empty($src))` check will then fail, and the image will not display.

Comment: I've added comments to the image snippet code to make it more obvious what it is doing.

Comment: there is some ´emptyempty´ in the code. Can you see it? its 2 places. That gave me errors

Comment: is there any easy way to change this code to post only featured_image too? Would be a great alternative. thanks again for the solution!!

Comment: if(has_thumbnail()){ // do featured image code } else { //do code you're already using }

Comment: and empty empty fixed